# Poter usare "come" invece di "di" nella frase: "Maria ha la stessa età di Luca"

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, comparison

Di solito, per fare un confronto tra due persone e dire che sono simili in qualcosa posso dire:

*[persona 1] è [aggettivo] come/quanto [persona 2]*

Esempi:

```
Luca è alto come/quanto Maria 
Luca è giovane come/quanto Maria
```

*[persona 1] ha/fa/altro verbo .... come [persona 2]*

Esempi:

```
Luca porta i pantaloni come Maria
Luca ha gli occhi blu come Maria
```

Posso usare "come" invece di "di" in questa frase: "**Maria ha la stessa età di Luca**"?
A me sembrerebbe di no, però non so proprio spiegare il perché! Mi potreste spiegare come mai?

Comment: A mio avviso, la ragione è che la parola "stessa" implica già la comparazione quindi il "come" diventa ridondante. Similmente, "Luca è alto quanto Maria" oppure "Luca è *altrettanto* alto che Maria" ma non "Luca è altrettanto alto quanto Maria", poiché "altrettanto" già significa "tanto quanto".

Comment: Esatto, anche la frase *Luca ha gli occhi blu come Maria*, se formulata con la parola 'stessi', utilizza **di** al posto di **come**: *Luca ha gli stessi occhi blu di Maria*

Comment: @secan dire che usare il come sarebbe ridondante mi aveva convinta finché non ho pensato alla frase "Luca ha l'età di Maria" in cui non si può comunque usare il "come" anche se non sarebbe ridondante.

Answer (score -2):

semplicemente perchè il `come` viene usato come similitudine, 
tendenzialmente per attribuire un aggettivo.

Mentre il risponde alla domanda "di chi" il **complemento di specificazione**.

Come ad esempio:

> Luca ha gli stessi occhiali di Maria

Comment: Questa spiegazione per un non madrelingua non spiega nulla purtroppo

Comment: @E.V. Neanche per un madrelingua...